# How to get data for XMLHTTP requests using scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

A web page where the data I am intersted in has some XHR requests. 
I have got the url of the XHR request using developer tools.
Now how to implement the same in my spider.py file and how to get all the values in that.I have started with scrapy unaware of working with ajax post requests as this. Please guide me on how to get the data and want the fields available to be stored in an excel file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to simulate a web request from inside your script. To do this, you can do something like this:

```
url = 'your url string'
req = scrapy.Request(url,
                     method='POST',
                     body='{"filters": []}',
                     headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                     callback=self.parser2)
yield req
```

This is just an example and will probably *not correspond to your exact use case*. You'll need to investigate the actual request to determine what headers to send, the body text, and whether you want to do a callback or not.

Comment: This is the url [link](https://cognizant.taleo.net/careersection/indapac_itbpo_ext_career/      moresearch.ftl?lang=en#) from which I actually want to scrape.And my XHRrequest is from this url [link](https://cognizant.taleo.net/careersection/indapac_itbpo_ext_career/moresearch.ajax).My code with in parse is like this:<br/> 'def parse(self, response):
  hs = Selector(response) items = []
  for x in links: item =  CrawlsiteItem()
   #item["title"] = x.xpath(".//span[@class = 'titlelink']/a//text()").extract() items.append(item)
  return items `

Comment: The main problem is here that if you look at the XHR request you see that there are a lots of parameters which are sent to the server in the `POST` request. You have to find the minimum set of them to make your application clear to read.

Comment: @Muttonchop The data which I am looking for is visible in preview and response tags inside the network tab of developer tools. Now how to analyse this and fetch the data and to put the logic in my spider.

Comment: @SreeSindhuSruthi You're asking really broad questions without any insight as to what you've already done. Each browser is different and the tools to understand the web requests are different.

Comment: @Muttonchop Actually I just started with scrapy framework and I have understood how to fetch data of static pages. For ajax requests, I am not getting any tutorials or links which helps me understand on the data scraping. So, I am trying to take help in the forum. Comments has character restrictions because of which I am unable to share my work or images.

Comment: You are more than welcome to edit the original question with more information regarding the specific issue you are having.  That way I can edit my answer to give a more complete answer.